# Sprite Kit Game Scene changes when it is not supposed to

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

In a game that I am currently building a person is supposed to catch balls that are falling from the sky. If the ball goes off the screen it means he didn't catch the ball, and so the scene is supposed to change to a game over scene. The problem is that even if the ball doesn't go below the screen the screen will change. But the screen will change to a blank screen so instead of the `GameOverScene()`.

Here is the code for the `GameScene()`...

```swift
//
//  GameScene.swift
//  catch balls
//
//  Created by Ankith Udupa on 8/10/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 UdupaLabs. All rights reserved.
//

import SpriteKit

var score = 0
var lossFlag = false

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    var person = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "guyLeft_1.png")
    var left = true
    let kScoreHudName = "scoreHud"

    struct PhysicsCategory {
        static let None  : UInt32 = 0
        static let All   : UInt32 = UInt32.max
        static let Ball  : UInt32 = 0b1
        static let Person: UInt32 = 0b10
    }

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        var content = false
        //set up screen
        setUpScreen()

        //set up the physics 
        physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

        //add ball
        runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(
            SKAction.sequence([
                SKAction.runBlock(addBall),
                SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0)
                ])
            ))

    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */
        left = !left

    }


    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
       if ((person.position.x > person.size.width/2) && (person.position.x < size.width-(person.size.width/2))){

        if left {
            var leftMove = SKAction.moveByX(5, y: 0, duration: 0.1)
            person.runAction(leftMove)
        }

        if !left { // or use an if-else construct
            var rightMove = SKAction.moveByX(-5, y: 0, duration: 0.1)
            person.runAction(rightMove)
        }


    }

    }

    //random number gen functions
    func random() -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF)
    }

    func random(#min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return random() * (max - min) + min
    }

    //add ball function
    func addBall(){

        //create ball sprite
        var ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball.png")

        //create physics for ball
        ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ball.size) // 1
        ball.physicsBody?.dynamic = true // 2
        ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ball // 3
        ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Person // 4
        ball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None // 5
        //generate random postion along x axis for ball to spawn
        let actualX = random(min:ball.size.width/2+1, max: size.width - ball.size.width/2-1)

        //set balls positon
        ball.position = CGPoint(x: actualX, y: size.height - ball.size.width/2)

        //add ball to scene
        addChild(ball)

        //determine speed of ball
        let actualDuration = random(min: CGFloat(3.0), max: CGFloat(5.0))

        //create movement actions and run them
        let actionMove = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x:actualX, y:  -ball.size.width/2), duration: NSTimeInterval(actualDuration))

        let actionMoveDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()

        let Loss = SKAction.runBlock() {
            let reveal = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(0.1)
            let gameOverScene = GameOverScene()
            self.view?.presentScene(GameOverScene(), transition: reveal)
        }
        ball.runAction(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, Loss, actionMoveDone]))

    }

    //setUpScreen
    func setUpScreen(){
        self.backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()

        var ground = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height * 0.2))
        ground.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.frame.size.height * 0.1)
        ground.fillColor = SKColor.blueColor()
        self.addChild(ground)

        person.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.frame.size.height * 0.2)
        setUpPersonPhysics()
        self.addChild(person)

    }

    //set up person physics
    func setUpPersonPhysics(){
        person.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: person.size)
        person.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        person.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Person
        person.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ball
        person.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
        person.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    }

    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        // 1
        var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
        var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody
        if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
            firstBody = contact.bodyA
            secondBody = contact.bodyB
        }
        else {
            firstBody = contact.bodyB
            secondBody = contact.bodyA
        }

        // 2
        if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.Ball != 0) &&
            (secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.Person != 0)) {
               personDidCollideWithBall(secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, ball: firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)
        }

    }

    //called when person collides with ball
    func personDidCollideWithBall(person:SKSpriteNode, ball:SKSpriteNode) {
        println("hit")
        ball.removeFromParent()
        score++
    }

}
```

and here is the code for the `gameOverScene()`...

```swift
//
//  gameOverScene.swift
//  catch babies
//
//  Created by Ankith Udupa on 8/12/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 UdupaLabs. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class GameOverScene: SKScene {

    var message = "Game Over"

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        self.backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
        setUpTextOutPut()

    }
    func setUpTextOutPut(){
        let gameOverLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Superclarendon-Black")
        gameOverLabel.text = message
        gameOverLabel.fontSize = 40
        gameOverLabel.fontColor = SKColor.orangeColor()
        gameOverLabel.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)
        addChild(gameOverLabel)

        let scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Superclarendon-Black")
        scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
        scoreLabel.fontSize = 40
        scoreLabel.fontColor = SKColor.orangeColor()
        scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2-50)
        addChild(scoreLabel)

    }
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is with your addBall method,

```
 //add ball function
    func addBall(){

        //create ball sprite
        var ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball.png")

        //create physics for ball
        ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ball.size) // 1
        ball.physicsBody?.dynamic = true // 2
        ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ball // 3
        ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Person // 4
        ball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None // 5
        //generate random postion along x axis for ball to spawn
        let actualX = random(min:ball.size.width/2+1, max: size.width - ball.size.width/2-1)

        //set balls positon
        ball.position = CGPoint(x: actualX, y: size.height - ball.size.width/2)

        //add ball to scene
        addChild(ball)

        //determine speed of ball
        let actualDuration = random(min: CGFloat(3.0), max: CGFloat(5.0))

        //create movement actions and run them
        let actionMove = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x:actualX, y:  -ball.size.width/2), duration: NSTimeInterval(actualDuration))

        let actionMoveDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()

        let Loss = SKAction.runBlock() {
            let reveal = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(0.1)
            let gameOverScene = GameOverScene()
            self.view?.presentScene(GameOverScene(), transition: reveal)
        }
        ball.runAction(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, Loss, actionMoveDone]))


    }
```

If you look at the method properly, you ask to run the sequence to the sprite and inside runBlock, you move to another scene. Do you need to check if the ball is outside bounds inside this block and only then present your game over scene ?

Should it be something like this,

```
let Loss = SKAction.runBlock() {
                if ball.position.x > self.size.width + ball.frame.size.width * 0.5  || ball.position.y < ball.frame.size.height * 0.5 {
                    let reveal = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(0.1)
                    let gameOverScene = GameOverScene()
                    self.view?.presentScene(GameOverScene(), transition: reveal)
            }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering. But this doesn't really work. ball.position isa CGPoint so you can't compare it to a cgfloat. did you mean ball.position.y?

Comment: I tried that too  but it still didn't make any difference. It took away the glitch but it didn't change scenes when the ball touched the ground.

Comment: Yes that does not because it checks x only, I made a edit that compares y also.

Comment: wait never mind the game displayed the same behavior i talked about in my question..